# How can you use a WPF window as owner for a JDialog?

Tags: java, .net, wpf, window, jdialog

I wonder if it is possible to have a `Java Class` where you have a contructor like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    JDialog dialog;

    public SomeClass(Window owner) {
        dialog = new JDialog(owner, "My Dialog", true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 1) {
            new SomeClass((Window) args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way how you could use that in a `WPF application` so that you could call something like `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("java -jar myprog.jar");` and use the `WPF Window` as parameter? Or is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. See [can I make JDialog to be modal using native system window as a parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907641/can-i-make-jdialog-to-be-modal-using-native-system-window-as-a-parent).

If `JDialog` supported setting native window handles as owners, you could have passed `HWND` of WPF window as an integer parameter, but `JDialog` doesn't.

Comment: Damn, so no Java application dialog inside WPF :( Thanks for clarifying.