# Is it possible to run a process within a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, process, jframe

In C# I can obtain the handle of a specific window and assign that handle to a component. I was wondering if it is possible to do the same within Java. I want to run a new process and show the running process within a JFrame.

Comment: No, well, kind a, but probably won't result in what you think.  Basically, you need to use a AWT based class ... not sure if you need to use `Canvas` or `AWT`, which then make inter-operability issues with Swing (Z-ordering for one)

Comment: Maybe [Embed HWND (Window Handle) in a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809713/embed-hwnd-window-handle-in-a-jpanel)? But then you're going to need some way to get the Window Handle of the process so you can embedded it, which is entirely another question - Maybe look at the JNA libraries